# Does perl6 have a class method equivalent to the MAIN sub?

Tags: raku

Or similar to java's main() method? In other words a method that executes first, with the possibility of reading one or more parameters from the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it's called [MAIN](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/MAIN) and it has autoparsing for terminal parameters. Futhermore, it can even be a [multi sub](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/multi#(Functions)_declarator_multi) (supporting different signatures), have defaults, mark as required and do type validation, e.g.:

```
#|(optional description for USAGE message) 
sub MAIN( Int :$length = 24,
           :file($data) where { .IO.f // die "file not found in $*CWD" } = 'file.dat',
           Bool :v(:$verbose) #`( -verbose, --verbose, -v or --v ) )
{
    say $length if $length.defined;
    say $data   if $data.defined;
    say 'Verbosity ', ($verbose ?? 'on' !! 'off');

    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But does this work from within a class? If I define either a sub or a method named MAIN in a class, it does not seem to execute.

Comment: you can add a MAIN to a class and execute the class directly (e.g. when developing), but like in Java, it has no much use in the real program. What do you want to do? Initialize a resource? The MAIN is called from the main script, not from a class.

Comment: If you wanted your script to fire up a method in a class you'd include that in the `MAIN` sub in your script. 
A good example for a use case for this is Mi6 where the bin script installed as part of it is a wrapper around various class calls.

https://github.com/skaji/mi6/blob/master/bin/mi6

Comment: OK. I was simply curious if a "static" MAIN-like method within a class existed. I am writing a test class, which just calls other classes. Though I can also do this as a script using the MAIN sub. For me it is merely a matter of convention.

Comment: You *can* put it in a class and it will run. This is handy if you're testing the command line parameters, but for one reason or another don't want to write a test. But you can also put randon code in a class and it will run as well. This is not restricted to functions handling parameters. "say 'FOO'" will show that output when you load the code.

Comment: OK. if I define either a sub or a method named MAIN in a class (ie. TestClass) and run perl6 TestClass.pm6 it does not seem to run the MAIN method though.

Comment: if you want a `method MAIN` to be picked up, you can mark it `is export`, which will create a sub in the outer scope, i.e. where you'd normally put a `sub MAIN`. Note, however, that it'll have a first parameter that wants to be filled with an instance of your class, which the normal `MAIN` implementation probably doesn't know how to do. You can get around that by declaring the type of invocant in the signature, like `method MAIN(Str $first-arg: Str $other-arg) {}` for example